# How to find the limit of $n \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4 n^2+10}\right)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I don't even know how to start solving such a problem

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(n \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4 n^2+10}\right)\right).$$

I started in solution with parts:

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=1$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4 x^2+10}\right)=$ indeterminate

$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot1= \infty$

but how to combine the solution please?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: If you don't show any effort your question will be closed/downvoted. You must have tried at least something ? Please **edit your post** to show us what you tried.

Comment: This limit seems very oriented to nihilism, as noticed you should show your work and effort on it,

Comment: Partial hint: do you know an equivalent of $\ln(1 - x)$ when $x \to 0$?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: $1 - \frac{1}{n} \neq \frac{1}{n - 1}$, so your first limit is not going to help. What we have is that $\ln(1 - x) \sim -x$ when $x$ tends to $0$, thus $\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \sim -\frac{1}{n}$, hence $n\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \sim- n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = -1$ converges to the finite limit $-1$. This means that all that remains is determining what happens with the $\cos$ term.

Comment: sorry for the mistake in writing. I reedit the post as this $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=1$

Comment: @user You both are wrong, in fact $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=0$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Opsss, of course, I meant indeed $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n=-1$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes indeed$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\right ]=-1$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You're right, but surprisingly [Wolfram Alpha's output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+as+n+approaches+infinity+of+cos%28pi+*+sqrt%284n%5E2%2B10%29%29) claims otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually with $n$ we indicate an integer and we have that

$$n \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)= \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to \ln \frac 1e=-1$$

and since

$$\sqrt{4 n^2+10}=2n\left(1+\frac{5}{2n^2}\right)^\frac12 =2n+O\left(\frac1n\right)$$

we also have

$$\cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4 n^2+10}\right)=\cos  \left(2\pi n+ O\left(\frac1n\right)\right) =\cos \left(O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\to 1$$

therefore the limit is equal to $-1$.

---

Note that if we assume $n$ real the limit for $\log$ part is also equal to $-1$ but the part for $\cos$ doesn't exists and so the overall limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for your efforts, the problem is solved now :)

Comment: @engnajjar Well done! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

First, one has $$\ln \left(1- \dfrac{1}{n} \right) \sim -\dfrac{1}{n}$$

so $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} n \ln\left(1- \dfrac{1}{n} \right) = -1$.

Then, one has
\begin{align*}
\cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4n^2+10}\right) &= \cos\left(2\pi n \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{10}{4n^2}}\right) \\
& = \cos\left[2\pi n \left(1 + \dfrac{10}{8n^2}+ o \left(\dfrac{1}{n^3} \right)\right)\right] \\
& = \cos\left( \dfrac{10 \pi}{4n}+ o \left(\dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)\right) \\
& \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \cos(0)=1
\end{align*}

Combining all these things together, you get that
$$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left(n\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos \left(\pi \sqrt{4n^2+10}\right)\right) = -1}$$

Comment: $\ln \left(1- \dfrac{1}{n} \right) \sim -\dfrac{1}{n}$. I won't deny it, but where do you get this from?

Comment: @Dominique For a regular enough function like $x \mapsto \ln(1 - x)$, you can find an equivalent by taking the first nonzero term in the expansion given by Taylor's formula. For $\ln(1 - x)$ that first term is $-x$.

Comment: @Dominique If you don't know Taylor expansion, one can argue that $$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x-1} = \dfrac{\ln(x)-\ln(1)}{x-1} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow 1} \ln'(1)=\dfrac{1}{1} = 1$$ Subtituting $x$ by $1- \dfrac{1}{n}$ (which tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$), you get that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)}{- \frac{1}{n}} = 1$$ i.e. $$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} n\ln \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n} \right)= -1}$$

Comment: @Dominique I also suggest $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^n\to \frac1e \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} n\ln \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n} \right)= \lim_{ \rightarrow +\infty} \ln \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^n= \ln\frac1e= -1$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thanks a lot my friends for your efforts :)